# error in upload file to ftp with ftp_nb_fput

Tags: php, ftp

I wrote this code for upload file via ftp.

```
<?php

$file = 'index.php';

$fp = fopen($file, 'r');

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// Initate the upload
$ret = ftp_nb_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_BINARY);
while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {

   // Do whatever you want
   echo ".";

   // Continue upload...
   $ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);
}
if ($ret != FTP_FINISHED) {
   echo "There was an error uploading the file...";
   exit(1);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

and I get this error:
Warning: ftp_nb_fput(): Could not open data connection to port 2804: Connection refused
I disable my firewall but not work!

Comment: Try running in pasv mode, `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);` Also please use `ftp_close($conn_id)` when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running in pasv mode, ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); Also please use ftp_close($conn_id) when you're done.

Thanks  Ohgodwhy!